# Regex String Replacement/Value Increment on Part of Match

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I am trying to increment a specific value in a text file using a shell perl script

Here is my file:

```
foo=123
bar=456
baz=789
```

Here is the shell command I am trying to use:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/bar=(\d+)/$1 + 1/ge' myfile.txt
```

However, that loses the "bar=" part.  How can I match on "bar=456" and just increment to 457?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match the `bar=` into a group as well, eg;

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(bar=)(\d+)/$1.($2 + 1)/ge' myfile.txt
```

Comment: sweet... I tried it, but didn't add a '.' between $1 and $2.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably make sure you are not matching partially by using beginning of line anchor `^`. You can also make use of a lookbehind assertion `(?<= ... )` to keep the first part of your match, or `\K` if your Perl version supports it. You also do not need to put a dash before each individual switch.

```
perl -pie 's/(?<=^bar=)(\d+)/$1 + 1/ge'
```

Or with `\K`:

```
perl -pie 's/^bar=\K(\d+)/$1 + 1/ge'
```